# Equation of a Tangent Plane and Surface Area

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For the surface with parametric equations $r(s,t)=⟨st,s+t,s−t⟩$, find the equation of the tangent plane at $(2,3,1)$.
Find the surface area under the restriction $s^2+t^2\leqslant 1 $

For the first part, I don't know where to start. You either have to do a Jacobian or find a third coordinate for $r(s,t)$ because somehow it is a vector of three dimensions but only two variables which does not make much sense.

Comment: I inserted mathjax for your equation and restriction - is it now what you want? And by the way - you have 3 coordinates in parametric equation - if you didn't wrote it, at least read it.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the tangent plane is $z = r(2,1) + r_s(2,1)(s-2) + r_t(2,1)(t-1)$. Regarding the second point, attempt to visualize the geometric interpretation of $s^2 + t^2 \leq 1$. This, coupled with a change of variables, should provide the necessary information for determining the required area.